# why does the program stops on scanf ... if that line is removed it works correctly

Tags: c, string, pointers, literals

```
int main() {
    char *name;
    int howMany, i;

    printf("how many character do you want to enter: ");
    scanf(" %d", &howMany);     /*why does it stop here */
    name = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    printf("enter characters ");
    gets(name);
    puts(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It stops there  because it is waiting for you to enter an integer number.

Comment: i think you mean like this : `name = (char *)malloc(howMany * sizeof(char));`

Comment: `name = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));` --> `name = malloc(howMany + 1);`

Comment: Btw, `gets()` should never be used (it's not part of C anymore). Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Because your unspoken expectation of a single-keystroke being accepted for `howMany` and thusly moving on to your buffer allocation is misplaced.

Comment: @chux why do you choose `howMany + 1`

Answer (score 2):

Your program has problems:

- You should check the return value of `scanf()` ;
- You should not use the obsolete and unsafe function `gets()` ;
- You should allocate `howMany + 1` bytes instead of `5`. The extra byte is for the null terminator ;
- You should check the return value of `malloc()` ;
- `gets()` reads and stops on the pending newline `scanf()` left in the input stream. The observed behavior is probably this:

  - you are prompted to enter *how many character do you want to enter: *
  - you type a number followed by a newline
  - the program exits immediately

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *name;
    int howMany, i, c;

    printf("how many character do you want to enter: ");
    if (scanf(" %d", &howMany) == 1) {
        /* read the remainder of the line, including the newline character */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        if (howMany <= 0) {
            printf("invalid number: %d\n, howMany);
            return 1;
        }
        name = malloc(howMany + 1);
        if (name == NULL) {
            printf("cannot allocate %d bytes\n, howMany + 1);
            return 1;
        }
        printf("enter characters ");
        for (i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            if ((c = getchar()) == EOF)
                break;
            name[i] = c;
        }
        name[i] = '\0';
        puts(name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thankyou very much .. the problem was with gets .Even after replacing with fgets it didnt work .. So i used scanf and it worked